# Could not find any matches for react-native:0.64.+ Required by:project :react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:react-native are available.
Required by:
project :react-native-video[image: react-native-video_Could not find matches for React Native 0.64+]

I have tried upgrading and downgrading react-native-video and react-native version  !!
Currently choosen following API's in package.json.

"react-native": "0.64.4",
"react-native-video": "^5.1.1",

Kotlin version - 212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46.
Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2

Everything was working fine till 2 weeks back , anything changed recently ?